# Maven dependency tree without install

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies

I would like to run the `mvn dependency:tree` command on a lot of projects, but I sometimes get this error (example on google guava):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Guava Maven Parent 31.1-jre:
[INFO]
[INFO] Guava Maven Parent ................................. SUCCESS [  9.360 s]
[INFO] Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java .............. SUCCESS [  1.473 s]
[INFO] Guava BOM .......................................... SUCCESS [  4.277 s]
[INFO] Guava Testing Library .............................. SUCCESS [  1.845 s]
[INFO] Guava Unit Tests ................................... SUCCESS [  4.133 s]
[INFO] Guava GWT compatible libs .......................... FAILURE [  8.632 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  34.051 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-15T15:22:05+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) on project guava-gwt: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.google.guava:guava-tests:jar:test-sources:31.1-jre in sonatype-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :guava-gwt
```

If I run `mvn install` before this error does not appear. My problem is that sometimes the `mvn install` does not work.

Is there a way to make `mvn dependency:tree` work without using `mvn install` before?

Comment: This: `n sonatype-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/)` looks like a problem in your `settings.xml` file... ? without the full pom it's hard to say...

Comment: If you need to do `mvn install` there is something wrong in your build...

Comment: Hi, for this example the main POM is https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v30.0/pom.xml and settings here https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v30.0/util/settings.xml

Comment: If there is a way to make it run by excluding maven repository external dependencies, it's also good to me.